# Ambiguity in generic type initialization

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

taking the following simple template function that works fine:

```
template<typename T>
double Average(T tArray[], int nElements)
{
    T tSum = T(); // tSum = 0
    for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < nElements; ++nIndex)
    {
        tSum += tArray[nIndex];
    }
    return double(tSum) / nElements;
}
```

I've changed the first line to `T tSum()` and it was not compiled because the compiler thinks that tSum is a function and can not be used in an + operator in the for loop. Could you please tell me what is the difference between these following types of initializations of generic types?

- Type var = Type();
- Type var();

I thought it would be possible to replace these lines considering that for example both `int var()` and `int var = int()` are the same!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse

Comment: You can add an `int... P` template parameter and then you can write `int var (P...);`.

Answer (score 1):

`Type var();` declare a function. `Type var = Type()` is what you want.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

In C++11, you may use `Type var{};`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but `Type var;` causes wrong result as it doesn't contain zero initialization for numeric types. If you run the code it always returns a large negative number.

Comment: The most generic way in C++03 is `Type var = Type();`.